# Cookie not showing in the developer console of firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies

I am using Firefox ESR 45.7.0.
I am setting a cookie which expires in 1 hour like this:

```
var now = new Date();
var time = now.getTime();
time += 3600 * 1000;
now.setTime(time);

document.cookie = 
    'myFavoriteCookie=bestValue' +
    ';expires=' + now.toUTCString() +
    ';path=/';
```

But the cookie does not show up after I set it:

[image]

If I write `document.cookie` in the console. then It appears in the console, so it exists.

It does fully work with chrome.

Comment: FYI ... much easier to do `now.setHours(now.getHours() + 1);` :p are you setting that cookie in the console or in actual code?

Comment: Nice, thanks for the tip :) I set it via script.

Comment: @Black Did you find a solution to this? I have the same problem! FF 78.4.0esr